# Laravel Auth: Return json instead of redirect

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am new to Laravel and i wanted to know how to make it so that i can return a message in json instead of redirecting or using the flash messages.

The reason for this is because my forms are being processed with Vuejs so a redirect wont do it for me.

Edit: I’m working with the Laravel auth package

Comment: take a look at `laravel/passport`

Comment: Take a look at [Laravel Docs #json-response](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses#json-responses)

Answer (score -2):

You can return json by using

```
return response()->json($data);
```

Comment: I know this, but the problem is, i dont know how to create the middleware auth so that it wont redirect me but return the json and i dont know where or how to change that